# VBA excel (Macros)

Tags: excel, vba

Can you help me with the proper code to used in VBA excel? For example if in column A , A1 text is **BUY**, I would like to perform a certain formula in the next column which is B1, wherein the formula would be like `=c4+c5+(d1*c6)+(d1*c7)` and when if the text in column A is **SELL**, the formula will be `=c4+c5+(d1*c6)+(d1*c7)+(d1*c6)` and for the rest, the calculations will be automatic when the condition on buy or sell is met. Thank you

Comment: This sounds like it could be done with formulas easily? If you really want to use VBA, look up how to reference cells, set cell formulas and how to use `If ... Then ... Else ... End If`

Answer (score 2):

So you just want to add the following formula to B1? No VBA needed.

```
= C4 + C5 + D1*C6*IF(A1="BUY", 1, 2) + D1*C7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub NameOfYourSub()
  Dim rg as Range
  Set rg= Range("NameOfTheCellToCheck")
  If rg.value = "BUY" Then
     Set rg.offset(0,1).Value= YOUR BIG FORMULA (don't forget to use Range("NameOfTheCell").value +/*.....)   
     //Otherwise 
     //Range("NameOfTheCellWhereToPutTheResult")=YOUR BIG FORMULA
  Else
    //The same syntax as above. 
  End If
  Set rg= Nothing
End Sub
```